# Определение местоположения

Tags: java, android, геокодирование

Есть код:

```
 GeoPoint currentLocation = new GeoPoint((formatLocation(null)), (formalLoc(null)), "hhh", "h",  1);

    private double formatLocation(Location location) {

            if (location != null)
                    return
                            location.getLatitude();
                    return 0;

    }

    private double formalLoc(Location location) {
            if (location != null)
                    return location.getLongitude();
                    return 0;

    }
```

А теперь вот в чем вопрос: требуется вместо `formatLocation` и `formalLoc` сделать другие методы определения местоположения. Эти получается, что посылают ноль, значит и вся остальная часть насмарку.

Comment: Вы хотите из null получить настоящие координаты?

Comment: @Владимир, или не из null, хоть как-то их получить..)

Comment: Ноль оно вернет если location == null. Или если соответствующая координата равна нулю. Значит, вам нужно передавать корректный location, не?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, надо, как это сделать

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html - не оно?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, я все-таки не до конца понимаю, как это "вживить" в мой случай..) не могли бы разъяснить..?

Answer (score 2):

Для начала, Вам надо определить `LocationListener` для того, чтобы обрабатывать изменения местоположения.

```
private final LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
        //Ваш код
    }
};
```

Затем, надо определить `LocationManager` и обновлять его

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, МИН_ВРЕМЯ,
            МИН_РАСТОЯНИЕ, mLocationListener);
}
```

Подробнее про параметры метода можно прочитать [в документации](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)

И не забудьте проверить, что вы прописали разрешения в манифесте,

Для определения местоположения по интернету:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Или по GPS:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

[Оригинал](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591147/how-to-get-current-location-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Вот есть хороший урок на определение местоположения с помощью GPS и сетей:

http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/291-urok-138-opredelenie-mestopolozhenija-gps-koordinaty.html