# Получение данных GPS в фоновом режиме и в спящем режиме устройства при минимальном расходе батареи

Tags: java, android

Как организовать слушателя в **android** на изменение координат?

Необходимо запустить сервис или ресивер на получение GPS координат 24/7, т.е. при старте устройства, а не приложения - оно начало опрашивать данные GPS и записывало в БД.

Подскажите направление, можно пример

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Определение местоположения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/424944/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Comment: Я все эти моменты прочитал, но не то, что нужно. Я хочу реализовать такой момент: Приложение определяет координаты каждые 5 секунд (по GPS или по Интернету), записывает в sqllite. Всё что я нашел это запуск в активити. Мне надо сервис или ресивер. Ещё бы учесть ново ведения android с API 21-22, они ограничивают работы сервисов. Есть класс GPSTracker, пробывал делать через AlarMeneger. т.е. суть самого вопроса: Запустил приложение и оно собирает GPS данные 24/7

Comment: Тогда вот здесь смотрите: [Получение координат при неактивном приложении](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/724233/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Comment: Вы нашли решение своей проемы?